# Get to rows info in one

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables:

T1

```
ID post_id *more columns like post date, etc.
1   100
2   101
3   102
```

T2

```
ID post_id subid1 subid2 text
1    100      1      1   AAA
2    100      1      2   BBB
3    101      1      1   FFF
4    102      1      1   HHH
5    102      1      2   NNN
```

If i want to get the info of, for example, the post 100, i will get the info of the table 1 and table 2 using a normal select * from t1,t2 where t1.post_id=t2.post_id... and i will get 2 rows: one with the subid1=1 and subid2=1 with the text AAA and another row with the subid1=1 and subid2=2 with the text BBB. But i would need to get only one row with both different texts, like:

```
post_id  text1 text2
100       AAA   BBB
```

I tried with left join and sub queries, but i always get 2 rows or a query error U_U
Does someone has any idea about how I can deal with it?

Thank you : )

Comment: what rdbms, and which version?

Comment: @Sam and not all non-rdbms specific answers perform equally. If you want run of the mill answers with average to poor performance, go for it

Answer (score 3):

What you seek is often called a "crosstab" query. The SQL language was not designed for dynamic column generation and thus most products provide no feature whereby you can have it dynamically generate the columns you want. However, you can produce a query that will return the information you want by statically defining the columns:

```
Select T2.post_id
    , Min( Case When T2.subid2 = 1 Then T2.text End ) As text1
    , Min( Case When T2.subid2 = 2 Then T2.text End ) As text2
From T2
Where T2.post_id = 100
Group By T2.post_id
```

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution: use two left join for each case.

```
select * from t1
  left join (select answertext as text1 from t2 where subid1=1 and subid2=1) D 
      on t1.postid=t2.postid
  left join (select answertext as text2 from t2 where subid1=1 and subid2=2) D 
      on t1.postid=t2.postid
```